# Testing a scala class with junit

Tags: scala, junit

I'm trying to implement a simple stack in scala and test it with both junit and scalatest to get a feel for the differences. However, I'm running into some issues.

Here is the scala class:

```
class Stack[T] {
    var list: List[T] = Nil

    def push(x : T) { list = x :: list }
    def pop() : T = {
        val head = list.head
        list = list.tail
        head
    }
    def isEmpty(): Boolean = list == Nil
}
```

I compiled this with scalac, and tried to call it from a plain java junit class like this:

```
public class StackTests {

    @Test
    public void testPush(){
        Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    }
}
```

However when I try to run StackTests:

```
java -cp ../junit/junit.jar:../junit/hamcrest-core.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore StackTests
```

.

```
...
There was 1 failure:
1) testPush(StackTests)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/List
    at StackTests.testPush(StackTests.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
...
```

The error message is pretty clear, but I don't know how to fix it. Do I have to reference immutable list in the java test class somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List`, `Nil` and `::` are in the Scala standard library, so put it in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example of what that would look like? I'm new to scala, I don't even know where the standard library is located.

Comment: Found it. Since I'm using homebrew, it was located at: /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.2/libexec/lib/scala-library.jar.